# moving the mouse to an object on the screen

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a program that can move the curser to an a object, this object will be displayed on the screen (ex: in the screenshot the fish (inside the blue circle will enter inside the big red circle) and when it does I need to move the curser on the fish)
[fish in circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZTv9.png)

Comment: You'll need to write code to do that, which you do not have appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: FYI, in common GUI practice, the mouse pointer is under the direct control of the human user. Generally apps should not be taking control of the mouse nor the mouse pointer. Also, in general GUI terminology, a mouse has a mouse pointer, and text has a cursor.